# HttpContext.Current is null for bots

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have the following code in a class which is called by a .NET page (asp.net webforms during page_load event):

```
public static bool BrowserSupportsJS
{
   get { return (HttpContext.Current.Session["js_support"] != null 
   && ((bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["js_support"]));
}
```

This line throws an exception for any bot: googlebot, bingbot etc

The exception is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object and it is on the get accessor line. It looks like HttpContext.Current is null.

Comment: Why not just check `HttpContext.Current` for null prior to accessing it?

Comment: That's right. Just check if it's null and return false for everything.

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston I doubt that `HttpContext.Current` is null in code that executes when an http request is received. It is more likely to be the `Session` since it relies on session cookies which bots do not normally support.

Comment: Are you sure its not `Session` thats `null`? I can't imagine being in a situation where your running asp.net code without a context. On the other hand, I can perfectly well imagine that a session could be impossible to set up (although I've never looked for this behaviour before).

Comment: I think that his question is `WHY` more than `how to fix it` fixing it is something **REALLY EASY** but how in earth can a request has null `httpcontext`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the `Session` for `null` like so:

```
public static bool BrowserSupportsJS
{
   get 
   { 
       if(HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
           return false;
       return (HttpContext.Current.Session["js_support"] != null 
           && ((bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["js_support"]));

   }
}
```